# Prevent Clipping of a QTableWidget Delegate's Editor in PySide

Tags: python, pyside, qtablewidget

How does one prevent clipping of custom editors in QTableWidget delegates?

[image: clipped editor in a QTableWidget]

I am working on a PySide project with some fancy data I would like to edit in a variety of ways from a QTableWidget.

To do this I define a custom QStyledItemDelegate which spawns a different editor for each column.  Widgets which have a custom size are resized according to their own internal method set_editor_rect, which is itself called by the delegate's updateEditorGeometry:

```
class Element(object):
...
...
  def set_editor_rect(self, editor, option):
      rect = option.rect
      rect.setTop(rect.top() - self.expand_top)
      rect.setBottom(rect.bottom() + self.expand_bottom)
      rect.setLeft(rect.left() - self.expand_left)
      rect.setRight(rect.right() + self.expand_right)
      editor.setGeometry(rect)
```

This works, but it clips the editor at the boundary of the table, meaning the bottom rows are not editable.(See Image)

Is it possible to set this editor not to clip or instead to raise it above its parent?

If all else fails, how do you have such editors pop up as a dialog above the table instead?  Do I abandon the concept of the delegate?

Comment: To work without delegate, you can put widgets in the cells (with `setCellWidget`). You can always create custom widgets if the default one don't suit.